# vba find top 3 values run time error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the top 3 values from a list, all numerical values, using large function in VBA. My codes have an error when I run it, Run-time error 1004 as unable to get Large property of the worksheetfunction class. Not sure if I define rng wrong. I tried both methods one in the comment section and still getting the same error. I also tried to define rng1, rng2 as variant since I wasn't sure how to define array in vba, but same error.

Column S has the values I want to get the top 3 or the largest 3 and column G has the corresponding values. Position wise, I want to paste the top 3 in w1, x1 and y1 and corresponding values in w2, x2 and y2. There will be no ties so don't need to worry about breaking a tie.

```
   Sub test()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim lr As Long
   Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
   Set ws = Worksheets("policies")
   lr = ws.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Set rng1 = ws.Range("S3:S" & lr)
   Set rng2 = ws.Range("G3:G" & lr)
   For i = 23 To 25
    For c = 1 To 3
   'Worksheets("policies").Cells(1, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng1, c)
   ws.Cells(1, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng1, c)
    Next c
        For j = 23 To 25
        ws.Cells(2, j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rng2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(1, i).Value, rng1, 0))
        Next j
   Next i
   End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to take out j and leaving just i and it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops will overwrite the previous loop and you will end up with the third largest in every cell you only need one loop:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
Dim i&, c&
Set ws = Worksheets("policies")
lr = ws.Cells(Cells.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = ws.Range("S3:S" & lr)
Set rng2 = ws.Range("G3:G" & lr)

For i = 23 To 25
    c = 26 - i
    ws.Cells(1, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng1, c)
    ws.Cells(2, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rng2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(1, i).Value, rng1, 0))
Next i

End Sub
```

I tested this and it works with simple data:

[image]